# Django Simple Left Join

Tags: django

How can I display all related values from my model and display in template as one?

```
class DentalProcedures(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    patient = models.ForeignKey(PatientInfo, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    proc_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    proc_tooth_no = models.CharField('Tooth No./s', max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)
    procedure = models.CharField('Procedure', max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    amount_charged = models.IntegerField('Amount Charged', null=True, blank=True)


class DentalPayment(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    procedureid = models.ForeignKey(DentalProcedures, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    patient = models.ForeignKey(PatientInfo, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    amount_paid = models.IntegerField('Amount Paid', null=True, blank=True)
    date_paid = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
```

I want to display the patient summary of payment including the, procedure name, amount charged and payment details.

View

```
class DentalPaymentDetailView(DetailView):
    context_object_name = "payment_detail"
    model = PatientInfo
    template_name = "patient/procedure_payment_detail.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(DentalPaymentDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        payment = DentalPayment.objects.filter(patient=self.kwargs['pk'])
        context["payment"] = payment.DentalProcedures_set.all()


        return context
```

Comment: Can you explicitly explain what you want to do? because i am not sure that this `DentalPayment.objects.filter(patient=self.kwargs['pk'])` will work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have some logic to provide the `patient_id`, try this

```
context["payment"] = DentalPayment.objects.filter(patient_id=patient_id).values('procedureid__procedure', 'procedureid__amount_charged', 'amount_paid', 'date_paid')
```

to get `total amount paid`,

```
from django.db.models import Sum

total_amount = DentalPayment.objects.filter(patient_id=patient_id).aggregate(tota_amount_paid=Sum('amount_paid'))
```

Comment: `self.kwargs['pk']` is my `patient_id`. It works for me. Thank you!

Comment: glad to hear that :)

Comment: Can I put in the same query where I can display the paid amount and the total amount paid?

Comment: What you mean by  `total amount paid`  ?

Comment: Annotating the values of the amount paid.

Comment: @CarlosFabiera I updated answer, Is that you needed?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165605/discussion-between-jerin-peter-george-and-carlos-fabiera).